What creature is on the wall in the Transfiguration classroom and Bingle & Blatch Shop?
As soon as you enter the Transfiguration classroom, on your right next to the stairs is a picture of some kind of creature.

I'm curious as to what creature this is. I haven't seen such a creature before.
The same creature is also on the wall in the Bing & Batch shop within Hogsmeade:

What is this?

I looked through the creature section of the Harry Potter fandom and wasn’t able to find anything. Keep in mind though that the quality of that page and its subpages was extremely poor, and many images were clearly fake (and that’s when the page had an image).

I think it is faun a creature from ancient Roman mythology. It has the upper body of a human and the lower body of a goat.

The faun (known originally as the satyr) came from Greek mythology first. Romans just copied them over, like everything else.
